# How do I reset random number, count, text, and label with button click c#

Tags: c#, forms, refresh

I am using Visual C# 2013. I have a form and I am wondering how to make my "Clear" button reset/refresh the whole form to the same state when I first clicked start (random number generated at form load, counter, textbox, and a label). For a number guessing form so that a user can play it again. Thanks in advance. Code is :

```
{
    int Answer; // declares the Answer variable outside button event
    int Guesses = 0;     // start counter outside button event
    int UserGuess;
    public frmGuess()
    {                               // generates random number outside button event so does not change on button click
        InitializeComponent();
        Random rand = new Random(); 
        Answer = rand.Next(100) + 1; // makes it range 1 to 100
    }
    private void btnGuess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtGuess.Text)) // input validation check to make sure not blank
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a whole number between 1 and 100", "Error!!");
            return;
        } //end if
        if (txtGuess.Text != "") // if its not blank, check to make sure its a whole number with try-catch
        {
            try  
            {
                UserGuess = int.Parse(txtGuess.Text);
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter a whole number between 1 and 100", "Error!!");
            }
        } // end if
        else
            UserGuess = int.Parse(txtGuess.Text);  // variable assign and code run
            Guesses ++;
            if (UserGuess > Answer)
            {
                txtGuess.Text = "";
                lblAnswer.Text = "Too high, try again.";
                Guesses++;
            }
            else if (UserGuess < Answer)
            {
                txtGuess.Text = "";
                lblAnswer.Text = "Too low, try again.";
                Guesses++;
            }
            else
            {
                lblAnswer.Text = "Congratulations the answer was " + Answer + "!\nYou guessed the number in " + Guesses + " tries.\nTo play again click the clear button.";
        } //end if
    } 
    private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  // clears Answer label and Guess textbox
    {
        txtGuess.Text = "";
        lblAnswer.Text = "";
    }

    private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // closes window
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Here is a screenshot when they have guessed the number! (I don't have enough rep to post an image yet) https://i.stack.imgur.com/hB9yV.png

Comment: What are you having trouble with? Do you know how to create an event handler for the Click event? Do you know how to assign state such as text, checked states, etc.? Please show the code you've already written in your attempt to solve this, explain what that code does now, and how that's different from what you wanted. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I am trying to make the "Clear" button reset the values and the form with a different random number so they can try guessing the number again

Comment: Well, your formatting makes me guess you dropped brackets after the outmost else, maybe?

Comment: yea missed hitting tab. its correct but same issue

Comment: I'm not really sure what your problem is. Currently, your code does `Guess ++;` and the code below it even if the user type a non-numeric value. Is that the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should put all of the "initialization to be reset" code into a method that can be shared by the constructor and the "Clear" button:

```
private void ResetForm()
{
    txtGuess.Text = "";
    lblAnswer.Text = "";
    Random rand = new Random();
    Answer = rand.Next(100) + 1;
    Guesses = 0;
}
```

(aside: you can actually just initialize the `rand` object once, as a readonly member field of the class (it can even be static if you like)...but in this case creating a new `Random` object each time you want to choose a new number, though not the most elegant approach, will work fine).

Then, call that method from your constructor and from the `Click` event handler:

```
public frmGuess()
{                               
    InitializeComponent();
    ResetForm();
}

private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ResetForm();
}
```

By the way, your "Guess" button handler could use some work too:

```
private void btnGuess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblAnswer.Text = "";

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtGuess.Text)) // input validation check to make sure not blank
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a whole number between 1 and 100", "Error!!");
        return;
    } //end if

    if (!int.TryParse(txtGuess.Text, out UserGuess))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a whole number between 1 and 100", "Error!!");
        return;
    }

    Guesses ++;
    if (UserGuess > Answer)
    {
        txtGuess.Text = "";
        lblAnswer.Text = "Too high, try again.";
    }
    else if (UserGuess < Answer)
    {
        txtGuess.Text = "";
        lblAnswer.Text = "Too low, try again.";
    }
    else
    {
        lblAnswer.Text = "Congratulations the answer was " + Answer + "!\nYou guessed the number in " + Guesses + " tries.\nTo play again click the clear button.";
    } //end if
}
```

The above removes some redundant code, fixes at least one bug, and gets rid of the need for exception handling.

Answer (score 0):

### EDIT

First, check out if you didn't drop brackets around `if (txtGuess.Text != "") ... else`(here) first.

```
private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  // clears Answer label and Guess textbox
{
    txtGuess.Text = ""; // to reset the TextBox
    lblAnswer.Text = ""; // to reset the Label
    Random rand = new Random(); // Doesn't it make Answer to be always the same integer?
    Answer = rand.Next(100) + 1; // to generate a new random answer
    Guesses = 0; // to reset the number of guesses
}
```

---

Just try `InitializeComponent();` inside the callback of `Button_Click`.

Comment: I tried that. When I tried guessing more numbers it just kept throwing my error message box.

Comment: You wouldn't want to call `InitializeComponent()` anyway. That doesn't just reset default values, it recreates all the objects in the form, but without properly disposing the old ones, and potentially failing to fully initialize the new ones (since the form is already loaded, it won't go through the window-showing logic).

Comment: That works partially, but doesn't add in things like clearing the textbox and label if they enter a non-integer or leave the box blank.

Comment: @Drakkhul You should `return;` right after an error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

try reset control :

```
foreach (Control ctl in this.Controls)
            {
                ctl.ResetText();
            }
```

Comment: tried that and getting Error 3 The name 'frmReset' does not exist in the current context

Comment: You can't assign to `this`.

Comment: try this foreach (Control ctl in this.Controls)
            {
                ctl.ResetText();
            }